# how to make an image fit to div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

how to use image as background of div ?

[I want to make this image as background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtyWP.png)

[and the result i got is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcS0i.png)

this is my code

```
 <s.Container
        ai={"center"}
        style={{
          backgroundImage: "url(" + "/config/images/bg2.png" + ")",
          backgroundPosition: "center",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
          position: "relative",
        }}
      > </s.Container>
```

Comment: Is the div height:width ratio the same as image? It should work with background-size: cover, so my only guess is maybe the image aspect ratio is not equals to divs aspect ratio.

Comment: how to make the image size match the div size if the div size is 100%?

Comment: That might be a clue, I had issues before with `width: 100%` using images. Try by using `width: 100vw` if you're trying to archive a full screen width, otherwise, just set a defined width. Hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `background-size:cover;` it will cover the entire visible area it's in while keeping the aspect ratio, and will overflow if it needs to, which is what it's doing. The size of the container it needs to fill is a different aspect ratio to the image you are using. I'm not sure if it's what you need (most unlikely), but you can try `background-image: contain;`. This contains the image to the space, respecting the aspect ratio of the image, but it's not guaranteed to completely fill the space top/bottom/left/right.

The approach you may need to take is using two separate background images combined with pseudo elements. An image strip for top & bottom (top will be right side up, bottom will be same image but flipped vertically using: `transform:scaleY(-1);`. Second image will be a sliver of the middle part that you can repeat vertically using `background-repeat:repeat-y;`.

You would definitely need to tweak this to fit your project, but this is the approach I would take. It depends on the content that it will hold, how wide you need it to be.

```css
.window {
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
  top: 2rem;
  background-size: 100% 30px;
  background-repeat-y: repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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")
}

.window > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.window::before {
  transform: translateY(-2rem);
  top: 0;
}
.window::after {
  transform: translateY(2rem) scaleY(-1);
  bottom: 0;
}

.window::before,
.window::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAiYAAABICAYAAADCrz5FAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAhGVYSWZNTQAqAAAACAAFARIAAwAAAAEAAQAAARoABQAAAAEAAABKARsABQAAAAEAAABSASgAAwAAAAEAAgAAh2kABAAAAAEAAABaAAAAAAAAAEgAAAABAAAASAAAAAEAA6ABAAMAAAABAAEAAKACAAQAAAABAAACJqADAAQAAAABAAAASAAAAABUHu/3AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAABWWlUWHRYTUw6Y29tLmFkb2JlLnhtcAAAAAAAPHg6eG1wbWV0YSB4bWxuczp4PSJhZG9iZTpuczptZXRhLyIgeDp4bXB0az0iWE1QIENvcmUgNi4wLjAiPgogICA8cmRmOlJERiB4bWxuczpyZGY9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkvMDIvMjItcmRmLXN5bnRheC1ucyMiPgogICAgICA8cmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uIHJkZjphYm91dD0iIgogICAgICAgICAgICB4bWxuczp0aWZmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3RpZmYvMS4wLyI+CiAgICAgICAgIDx0aWZmOk9yaWVudGF0aW9uPjE8L3RpZmY6T3JpZW50YXRpb24+CiAgICAgIDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPgogICA8L3JkZjpSREY+CjwveDp4bXBtZXRhPgoZXuEHAAAFTUlEQVR4Ae3ZQWpbVxgF4PssGaeyCy6x6cCOMXSWUTYQyCzTDktxB11Bt9CuIFvQoAvoEko7zjid1TWFBrtQBSdq3EpWTcCQDO9//xsU+gmEZfHOee99Ex2kUjwIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIECBAgAABAgQIEKgTGOoOX9+jT+7d+3wo17vre4WujAABAgQI9BUYXb76YTqbzfqepW/7uG/9+2xffbMahkfv84zORYAAAQIE1klgsbNzWmazH9fpmmqvZaM24HgCBAgQIECAQC8Bw6SXrF4CBAgQIECgWsAwqSYTIECAAAECBHoJGCa9ZPUSIECAAAEC1QKGSTWZAAECBAgQINBLwDDpJauXAAECBAgQqBYwTKrJBAgQIECAAIFeAoZJL1m9BAgQIECAQLWAYVJNJkCAAAECBAj0EjBMesnqJUCAAAECBKoFDJNqMgECBAgQIECgl4Bh0ktWLwECBAgQIFAtYJhUkwkQIECAAAECvQQMk16yegkQIECAAIFqgXF1olPgy4ODBxvDsButv7v30e4wDNG4HAECBAgQ+OAF5n8vHpwcHobvY7xYnE6fPz8NFyQE12aYbGwMT8pQHkXv6f79/bK3P4nG5QgQIECAwAcv8PNPZ0/mr/4J38dyc/T1TXgaLkgI+iknAVEFAQIECBAgkCNgmOQ4aiFAgAABAgQSBAyTBEQVBAgQIECAQI6AYZLjqIUAAQIECBBIEDBMEhBVECBAgAABAjkChkmOoxYCBAgQIEAgQcAwSUBUQYAAAQIECOQIGCY5jloIECBAgACBBAHDJAFRBQECBAgQIJAjYJjkOGohQIAAAQIEEgQMkwREFQQIECBAgECOgGGS46iFAAECBAgQSBAwTBIQVRAgQIAAAQI5AoZJjqMWAgQIECBAIEFgnNDxpuKL4+Pjlq6Pd0ZlubgOVyyW12XRkA+fWJAAAQIECKyJwGR7s0zmm/GrGYbdls/zO7PZbHrzjF9AKUNL+O3sV0cHv67KcPz2ezWvHz48Knv7k5rIO8denM/L1evlO+/5hwABAgQI/J8E9j+dlK2tUfiWnz79o5z99iKcvwl+9/3Z79+2FPgpp0VPlgABAgQIEEgVMExSOZURIECAAAECLQKGSYueLAECBAgQIJAqYJikciojQIAAAQIEWgQMkxY9WQIECBAgQCBVwDBJ5VRGgAABAgQItAgYJi16sgQIECBAgECqgGGSyqmMAAECBAgQaBEwTFr0ZAkQIECAAIFUAcMklVMZAQIECBAg0CJgmLToyRIgQIAAAQKpAoZJKqcyAgQIECBAoEXAMGnRkyVAgAABAgRSBQyTVE5lBAgQIECAQIuAYdKiJ0uAAAECBAikCgy3bSdHh6vb15G/jx9/Vibbm5Hom8zF+bxcvV6G84IECBAgQIBAm8And++U7YbP8mfP/iy/3Dyjj1UZpr4xierJESBAgAABAukChkk6qUICBAgQIEAgKmCYROXkCBAgQIAAgXQBwySdVCEBAgQIECAQFTBMonJyBAgQIECAQLqAYZJOqpAAAQIECBCIChgmUTk5AgQIECBAIF3AMEknVUiAAAECBAhEBQyTqJwcAQIECBAgkC5gmKSTKiRAgAABAgSiAoZJVE6OAAECBAgQSBcwTNJJFRIgQIAAAQJRAcMkKidHgAABAgQIpAsYJumkCgkQIECAAIGogGESlZMjQIAAAQIE0gXGWY0X5/OytTUK1y2vw1FBAgQIECBAIEFg9tdVuXxxFW56eflvOHsb/A8VQGSdaliimgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

```html
<div class="window">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```